# Are there any examples of multinomial or logistic regression as an outcome model using propensity score weighting?

Tags: causality, logit, multinomial-logit

I apologize if this is an inappropriate question, but does anyone have more recent texts on implementing some type of covariate balance weighting scheme (entropy balancing, IPTW, etc) where the outcome is binary (logistic) or multiple categorical quantities (multinomial).

I've seen some articles regarding SMMs and its use with IVs, but am trying to use weighting techniques in my analysis.

Comment: What is the issue with using traditional PSM on a binary outcome that you would want to avoid?

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid anything. I just haven't seen much work on extra considerations when trying to apply PSM or IPTW or some other method when such weights or matches will later be used in multinomial logit/logit regressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of PS methods is that they allow you to run your outcome model as if the data had come from a randomized experiment (ideally, assuming all goes well and no residual confounding). So after you've conditioned on your PS (i.e., by matching or weighting), you can just estimate whatever model you would have estimated in a randomized experiment. If you want to estimate a multinomial logit, you can simply do that in your PS-matched or -weighted data.

No additional considerations apply for categorical outcome models than they do for continuous outcome models. For some models, the interpretation of the causal effect will differ than had you included covariates in the outcome model, but that is true whether you are doing so in a truly randomized experiment or in a PS-conditioned sample. One thing to note is that if you simply regress the outcome on the treatment in a PS-conditioned sample, the outcome model will be saturated and it won't matter which form you use. That is, you'll get the same estimate of the risk difference whether you use a logistic regression or linear regression on the binary outcome, and with robust standard errors (which you should always use with PS methods), the inferences will be identical too.

Comment: Thanks! This was definitely my intuition, but some colleagues seemed to have concerns about trying to adhere to too many parametric assumptions, and so I thought I'd scope the issue out.